# Using Shortcodes in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to insert the shortcodes [acf field="my_map"] and [acf field="links"] in place of the the_field('my_map') and the_field ('links') located in the $html string shown in the code below. I'm apparently not PHP savvy enough to make it work. Help please?

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'wpmudev_ppw_html' ) ) {
$html = '<div class="row top-spacer"><div class="col-md-8"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="'.the_field('macro_map').'" /></div><div class="col-md-4"><h5><?php the_title(); ?>Resource Links</h5>'.the_field('symbol_news_links').'</div></div>'; // html code to be protected (required)
$id = 1; // An optional unique id if you are using the function more than once on a single page
$description = 'video'; // Optional description of the protected content
$price = '1.50'; // Optional price for a single view. If not set, price set in the post will be applied. If that is not set either, Unit Price in the Global Settings will be used.
echo wpmudev_ppw_html( $html, $id, $description, $price );
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: Whichever method I try to insert the shortcodes, I get a syntax error. So I must not be putting my periods and apostrophies in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<?php the_title(); ?>` with `'.the_title().'`

Comment: I also had to change the_field to get_field because I'm using ACF.